# Obfusticate AJAX JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm making a webapp that uses AJAX to retrieve some JSON data created by a PHP file on my server.  There is no authentication involved, therefore there is no definitive way to stop someone else from calling the PHP file and using my data on their site.

I would at least like to obfusticate the JSON data in some way in order to stop casual & opportunist theft of my resources by non-expert programmers.  What would be the best practices for obfusticating JSON data?

Comment: Even if you obfuscate it, an attacker can read your source code to see what variable you use for what. Client-side scripts are visible for the user. If you don't want the user to see something, then don't give it to him.

Comment: Did you actually read the question?  I agree that expert programmers will not struggle to get around this, but I want to prevent the CASUAL & OPPORTUNIST theft by non-expert programmers.

Comment: "*Best practises for obfuscating*" are always to make it as unreadable as you can while using a minimal amount of additional space. Choose any algorithm yourself.

Comment: I am not an expert programmer, I am 15, but would break most JSON obfuscation if I have the source code in which you use the JSON.  So I don't think obfuscation will help very much. @MattParkins

Comment: Irrespective of whether you think it would help much or not, what are the best practices of obfustication of JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's pretty trivial to find a good JSON parser, which, as long as your JSON was valid, would neatly extract the correct information from your JSON, I think it's going to be quite hard to get much security out of obfuscation.

If you really wanted to go with this, perhaps the best bet is to litter your JSON with data that is modelled to *look* relevant, but is in fact just junk/random data. At least this way it might make it harder for someone to make out what the meaningful data is, amongst all the 'noise' that you introduce.

Again, for meaningful security you really need something more traditional (authentication + encryption, really), but if you're constrained in not being able to do so, then this may be the best 'poor mans security' option.

Comment: @11684 - my bad, should have been clearer - obviously auth + encryption, since the OP is concerned about preventing unauthorised access. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways you can make your data more inconvenient to consume, but this doesn't really help you in terms of security. You should implement some sort of authentication token.

Comment: Can't do it under this system.